# Can I replace <table border=1>' with `<table>` + css: `table{...}`?

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

`table{border:1px solid #000;}` doesn't seem to work without the `border=1` statement.
In the same way as changing `<input width=30>` into `input{width:400px;}`, I would like to use `<table>` and declare the border in css only. Is that possible?

**Update**
my mistake was using

```
table{border-width:1px;}
```

instead of e.g.

```
table{border:1px solid #000;}
```

--which works fine.

Comment: It's not the same type of border, but yes that should be all that you need to do.

Comment: Can you give some code? If you are trying to declare styles inline then this is not the way to do it. (Never mind the fact that it's frowned upon.) See http://jsfiddle.net/pgtWH/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/opayi4)

[`border-collapse: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse) is important; without it you get doubled borders, [like this](http://jsbin.com/opayi4/2).

Comment: collapse tip is whort a million, thank you very much!

Comment: the border="1" appears to  create a sort of '3D' border?  With the top and left edge inset and the right and bottom edge outset?  How do I reproduce that effect?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely - that is the preferred way. You might have to style `td` as well as `tr`.

Comment: but if I use `<table>` the css styling doesn't seem to apply?

Comment: It will apply to the outside of the table, not to the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in CSS

```
 table
    {
    border:1px solid black;
    }
```

then you can use it in HTML

```
<table>
....
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, but if you use `table`, it will affect **ALL tables** in your html.

I suggest doing:

`<table class="myTable">` and then `.myTable { /*css*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Your style should be:

```
table td { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UasxM/).

Comment: You forgot to copy the link before pasting.

Comment: Just to let you know, that example only works because jsFiddle includes `table { border-collapse: collapse }` inside their reset: ([http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css](http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css)). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using, `<th>` for headers, with the code below, you will not get borders around our headers:

```
td { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

you will need to also add:

```
th { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

Regards,