# How to fix warning "A table row was 2 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)."

Tags: html, css, validation

I can't seem to figure out the problem of which the validation says "A table row was 2 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)" and  A table row was 3 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)". Also an error was presented: "Table column 3 established by element td has no cells beginning in it."
These warnings and the error regard the last five codes starting after `</table>` (the embedded table).

My table looks fine when published on the internet but won't go trough validation. Can't find the problem in my HTML-code.

I've tried adding and taking away `<tr>` and `<td>`but can't seem to do it right.

```
<table style="width:600px;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  <tr><!--this is where the first warning appears-->
    <td>C</td> 
    <td colspan="2">D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Warnings: "A table row was 2 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)"
"A table row was 3 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (1)".
Error: "Table column 3 established by element td has no cells beginning in it."

Comment: your first row has 1 column, you second row has 1 column and the row is not closed properly, your third row has 3 columns

Comment: Indent your code properly and you will find the issues

Answer (score 0):

Your second row (which contains a nested table) does not have `</td>` and `</tr>` closing tags.

You can always turn on table borders to see how the spanned/nested cells look like. Also please always use the proper indentation to understand the hierarhchy levels of the elements.

To turn on borders with css, take a look at this question: [Can I replace <table border=1>' with `<table>` + css: `table{...}`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394785/can-i-replace-table-border-1-with-table-css-table).

```
<!-- turned on a deprecated border to attribute to make it clear where the table cells are -->
<table style="width:600px;" border="1">

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <!-- I've commented out the inner table for lesser complexity -->

<!--            <table style="width:100%;">-->
<!--                <tr>-->
<!--                    <td>A</td>-->
<!--                    <td>B</td>-->
<!--                </tr>-->
<!--                <tr>-->
<!--                    <td>C</td>-->
<!--                    <td>D</td>-->
<!--                </tr>-->
<!--            </table>-->

            B <!-- added to see where this cell is -->
        </td> <!-- this td was not closed! -->
    </tr> <!-- this tr was not closed! -->

    <tr><!--this is where the first warning appears -->
        <td>C</td>
        <td colspan="2">D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```